# Add alt tags dynamically with src on WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm looking for a way to speed up the insertion of the alt tag dynamically, thanks to PHP in my HTML  tags.

Basically I have a page created in this format:
page-{slug}.php

I would like that inside this page all the images automatically take the alt tag of the image called in the src attribute of the  HTML tag.

Currently I am forced to do the following for each image (in this page there are about twenty images):

```
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/image.png" alt="image example">
```

Instead I would like each image to follow the following format (excluding the src attribute that calls the file):

```
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/image.png" alt="<?php echo alt_recovery_by_media(); ?>">
```

Is it possible to call with PHP the alt tag of the image inserted in the media?

For example this:
[image]

Better still if the PHP code in question is to be inserted in the functions.php file. Basically I would like a code that automatically calls the alt tag associated with that image and that is already in the alt tag of the media uploaded to WordPress.

Comment: I don't understand the question... can you explain it a bit better?

Comment: Can you share the code of how you displaying all images on-page?

Comment: I've updated my question, hopefully it's clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to do it myself by searching through the WordPress documentation.

This code is for finding the src:

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( IMAGE_ID, 'full' )[0];
```

Note that zero should be put to retrieve only the URL of the media file. You can find more info here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/

To get the alt tag you can use:

```
get_post_meta( IMAGE_ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
```

To retrieve the title of the image you can use instead:

```
get_the_title( IMAGE_ID );
```

Comment: What you wanted to do is exactly what I'm trying to do. So are you saying you where able to get the alt text by using the src? I assume you wrote a function and were then able to put something like this: `alt="<?php echo( alt_text_display() ); ?>"` to pull in the alt text. 

Is that correct? 
If so, would you mind sharing the full function?

Answer (score 0):

You can't derive the `alt` attribute value from the `src`. Typically, you would either hardcode the `alt` value in your PHP template (since you already hardcode the `src` and *know* its value), or you would use the Wordpress `wp_get_attachment_image()` function which will fetch the image by its ID and - among other values - also the `alt` value.

More about it here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/

Comment: So there's no way to do it automatically? I've seen that there are plugins that automatically add the alt value, however they do it for posts. Isn't it possible with PHP to do the same thing, but also for pages?

Comment: That function *can* add the `alt` attribute. But you get both the `src` and `alt` values at once, from the attachment ID, instead of getting the alt value from the src value.

Comment: Can you add a test code in the response? Thanks